# Trajectory of a rolling ball with uneven weight distribution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

A perfect ball is rolling on a plane. Without further forces, it would roll in a straight line, and that's it.

What, however, if the ball's weight distribution is uneven? For example, the ball might have a higher-density smaller ball placed within it, but being slightly off-center, so the center of gravity is not the geometric centroid of the ball. Note that I assume the ball to be solid, i.e., no moving parts within the ball.

How would this ball roll then? Which trajectories would be realizable by such a ball?

Sadly, I don't know enough mechanics to even write down the differential equations and simulate it on a computer...

Comment: This question is interesting, but probably too broad. I guess that, if the point the ball touches the plane and the center of gravity are in the vertical plane, than you have essentially a pendulum (where pendulum oscillations are equivalent to ball oscillations, but pendulum rotations are equivalent to the ball moving forward in a straight line, but with oscillating speed). Otherwise, the movement is perhaps a superposition of constant speed and pendulum movements.

Comment: An uneven ball will not purely roll. That is because the center of mass accelerates in the plane, there must be friction forces that do so. No this invalidates the first point, that the motion of a perfect ball on a plane is simple. When you consider slipping the motion is quite complex (see bowling mechanics).

Comment: There are two related types of unevenness at play. One has the center of mass at the geometric center, but the three mass moments of inertia values aren't equal (slight oblong shape), and the second is a shift in the center of mass (eccentricity) but the mass moments being equal. In general, you will have some combination of both. As it stands this question has way too many answers, and I am voting it closed as too broad. You can edit the question and provide a more limited scope with a more specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the center of mass is not coinciding with the normal force(vertically upwards), there will be a net torque about the point during the motion of the ball. When the heavier ball is towards the front, it will support rolling and increase the rotational speed of the ball. When it will go to back, it will give the opposite effect. As net energy is conserved, the ball will slip(considering no friction) if it started with pure rolling. You can write the equations as follow, just consider the motion of the center of the heavier ball. Let it's distance from the center of the main ball be r. Now, x will be equal to $r\cos \theta $,where theta is the angle from the horizontal axis passing through the center of the main ball. This will give you the torque as (M-m)gx where m is the mass of the equivalent part of the other side. This will give you $\tau=I\dot{w}$. Now, solve for the w where w is $d\theta/dt$. As I am not considering friction, the velocity in the horizontal direction will remain same. You should work out the case with the friction yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, I should clarify two points: first, I do consider friction, i.e., the ball will not glide; the point of contact will be momentarily still. Second, I guess the most interesting case is if the "smaller, denser" ball is not on the plane center-of-gravity/velocity vector. To be more precise, suppose the ball is currently moving forward but the smaller ball is to the left of the geometric centroid. In this case, I suspect the ball's movement will tilt leftwards, making the trajectory deviate from a straight line.

Comment: The law of rotational motion in vector form is $${\boldsymbol \tau} = \mathrm{I}_C \dot{{\boldsymbol \omega}}+{\boldsymbol \omega} \times \mathrm{I}_C {\boldsymbol \omega}$$ only when the rotation is fixed on a single axis the law simplifies down to "$\tau=I\dot{w}$" as you state.